# Multiple screen shots in one tiff file

Tags: screenshot, tiff

I need to take multiple screen shots and have them in one tiff file.  Is this possible, can anyone help me?

Comment: Knowing what OS you're using would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want the sceenshots arranged as a montage or as seperate overlapping layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, generate the screenshots, then use ImageMagick to combine them into a single file:

```
import ss1.png
import ss2.png
convert ss1.png ss2.png screenshots.tif
```